# how to remove the namespaces from the Element

Tags: java, xml, xmldocument, java-6

I am working with org.w3c.xml java library 
and encountering a few difficulties performing a few tasks:

1. I have an Element object; how can I remove namespaces from it and the predecessors?
2. How can I create a Document without the namespaces? I have tried

   ```
   DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
   DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("C:/Temp/XMLFiles/"+fileName+".xml"));
   ```

   Although it looks promising, it does not really work. I am still getting the doc with namespaces.
3. How do I create a document from an Element?

   ```
   Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
   doc.adoptNode(dataDefinition);
   ```

   where dataDefinition is an element, but it didn't work; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Does not work" is not sufficient to get an answer. *In what way* does it not work? Did you get an exception? If yes, what is it?

Comment: And I'm not believing that you're still seeing namespaces in a DOM after calling `setNamespaceAware(false)`. Please show complete code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: swear... later today ill edit my post ... thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try transforming it with the following [XSL](http://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/Remove-Namespaces.xsl):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

```
Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("xform.xsl")));
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
xformer.transform(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("input.xml")), new StreamResult(writer));
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```