# Why does calling setTextContent not appear in the transformed output?

Tags: java, dom, w3c

The following dom manipulation should result in a different output, but it doesn't. The println indicates it has worked, but the root node.toString() or using a [Transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223020/convert-an-org-w3c-dom-node-into-a-string) fails with equal results.

```
  private void markNewLinesInTextNodes(Node node) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength() ; i++) {
      Node child = node.getChildNodes().item(i);
      markNewLinesInTextNodes(child);
    }
    if (node instanceof Element) {
      Element el = (Element) node;
      if (el.getTagName().toLowerCase().equals("text")) {
        el.setTextContent(el.getTextContent().replaceAll("\n", "_LINEBREAK_"));
        System.out.println(el.getTextContent());
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
  if (el.getTagName().toLowerCase().equals("text")) {
    el.setTextContent(el.getTextContent().replaceAll("\n", "_LINEBREAK_"));
    System.out.println(el.getTextContent());
```

Then :

- are you sure of the selection ?
- how do you output it ?

try that:

```
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document),
      new StreamResult(buffer));
String result= buffer.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for verifying for me, so I'll mark this as correct given the information I provided. The real reason was because of the way the [jcabi api returns the node](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-xml/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jcabi/xml/XMLDocument.java#L284), but you couldn't have known that. Thanks again.